# File upload code for filedropjs.org plug in

Tags: jquery-file-upload, multifile-uploader

I am using Filedrop.js file (sample demo page is here [Filedrop.org](http://filedropjs.org/demo/) ).

I would like to have to upload.php file code for iframe and without iframe. Because I am testing that in IE9+ (upto IE 10,11).

Site has provided only code for js and not php.

Can anybody help me here?

Does anybody had worked with Filedrop.js before? If yes then please help me.

Answer (score 0):

you can check, git repo of FileDrop where you can get that you want...
[Please click on this link to show upload.php on FileDrop.js git repo](https://github.com/ProgerXP/FileDrop/blob/master/demo/upload.php)